# Forming an array within an array using np.append()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to form an array within an array. So that if I call Array_1[0] will give me the first value and Array_1[1] will give me the second value. In this instance, the first value will be 1 and the second value will be 2. Similar to tuples within a list. I have written the following code but I end up just with just one array containing all elements.

```
import numpy as np

list_A = [1,3,5]
list_B = [2,4,6]

Array_1 = np.array([])

for i,j in zip(list_A,list_B):
    Array_1 = np.append(arr = Array_1, values = [i,j])

print(Array_2.astype(int))

#output: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
#Desired output: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Any ideas if the desired output can be achieved through a numpy array. (btw not using a list and tuples)

Comment: If you let `arr = np.array([list_A, list_B])`, you can just call `arr.T`.

Comment: Look at the code for `np.append`.  It's just a poorly conceived cover for `np.concatenate`.  Or it nothing else read its docs.

Comment: Why not use lists?

Comment: Well, I already know how to do it with lists. The problem I am trying to solve is in the form of an array, so I wanted to keep it that way. Instead of converting it back and forth. as in array to list then back to array again, so on

Comment: Using `np.append` in iteration is not efficient.  But if you must use the axis parameter

Comment: `np.array(list(zip(A,B))` or `np.vstack((A,B)).T` or `np.stack((A,B),1)`.

Comment: You are making a 2d array, with shape (3,2).

Comment: Yep thanks, I think @MateenUlhaq earlier posted to use reshape, which is what I used in my code. Thanks again for all the answers